# Deleting fragment from xml file causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity with a FrameLayout which holds a fragment and a banner at the button:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_screen_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layoutDirection="locale" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_alarms_list"/>      

</LinearLayout>
```

I use a framelayout view to hold a fragment instead of a fragment view because i want to perforem fragment replacement on some condition so it has to be dynamic. Before that i had a fragment that looks like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
    android:name="packagename.AlarmListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    tools:context="packagename.AlarmListFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
```

After i removed the fragment every time i try to load the main screen i get this error:

> No view found for id 0x7f0d007b (packageName:id/alarm_detail_container)

even though the framelayout with the id of alarm_detail_container has nothing to do with this layout. It is only exists on the layout of the tablet. 
Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: IMHO the IDs have been regenerated. Try cleaning the project.

Comment: Do you have two different layouts for smartphone and tablet versions? You have to make sure that code will not run in smartohones

Comment: Tried to clean the project. Didn't help. And the code for smartphones run only on smartphones.